# Is my understanding of WebRTC protocol Correct?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, webrtc, stun

This is how I understand the protocol...

- user on browser get media stream
- generates own sdp (data on codecs, security, etc)
- creates an offer with it
- send this offer to server via signalling method (websocket)
- signalling server, looks who is this offer for and redirect it to
  that client
- client 2's browser gets the offer with sdp and in turn generate its
  own offer with its own sdp and send it to server
- server redirect client 2's offer to client 1. now both know each
  other specs.

Meanwhile, however...

- as soon as whichever client sends offer with sdp they also start to contact ICE (stun) server(s) to get possible reachable path to them via
  correct  PublicIP:Port:Protocol combo, which they also send to
  another client via signalling server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client 2 generates an answer (using createAnswer), not an offer. The main difference is that an answer is a subset of the capabilities (like codecs) contained in the offer.

Otherwise this sounds good.

Comment: where does `onnegotitaionneeded` fits in? and is it fired independently

Comment: you can either explicitly call createOffer or wait for ONN to tell you that you need to call createOffer. Its mostly a style question.

Comment: thanks.. i was thinking it'd break the program if ordering wasn't right