# Why is WebRTC local stream is showing nothing?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

what i'm trying to do is have p1 make connection to p2, p2 get webcam and stream it to p2. On all same page to practice webrtc.

but `onaddstream` i do get a stream, it has correct id and errors, but when i assign it to video element nothing happens.

However, I do get valid stream from p2, which is the one who requests the stream. If i set video equal to this stream then it shows webcam video.

This is the code

```
v = $0

pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection();
pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

pc1.onaddstream = (s) => {
    v.src = URL.createObjectURL(s.stream);
    window.s1 = s.stream;
};

pc1.createOffer({offerToReceiveVideo: 1})
.then((offer) => {
    pc1.setLocalDescription(offer);
    pc2.setRemoteDescription(offer)
})
.then(() => navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }))
.then((stream) => {
    pc2.addStream(stream);
    window.s2 = stream;
})
.then(() => pc2.createAnswer())
.then((answer) => {
    pc2.setLocalDescription(answer);
    pc1.setRemoteDescription(answer);
})
.catch((err)=>console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not signaling ICE candidates. Add:

```
pc1.onicecandidate = e => pc2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => pc1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
```

...and it will work.

**Side-tip:** check out your friendly web console deprecation warnings:

> ⚠ onaddstream is deprecated! Use peerConnection.ontrack instead.
>
> ⚠ URL.createObjectURL(MediaStream) is deprecated and will be removed soon.

E.g. like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yxbLvjm6/). The spec is almost done [evolving](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/the-evolution-of-webrtc/).

Comment: note chrome doesn't support ontrack natively yet, your example uses shim called adapter.js

Comment: can you look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208620/is-my-understanding-of-webrtc-protocol-correct

Comment: can you also explain why do everything after negotiationneeded event and why does your createOffer doesnt need {offerTORecieveVideo: true} is not needed, is it because one creating offer is the one sending the stream

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Right, you didn't tag this `google-chrome`. My answer is based on the spec, and `onaddstream` is no longer in the spec. [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) is the official WebRTC spec polyfill. The demo I linked to is a basic one. You're sending in the other direction. See [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/5Ltsmj04/) for that.

Comment: what about `offerTORecieveVideo: true`

Comment: can you please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411465/why-webrtc-is-giving-error-failed-to-set-remote-answer-sdp-called-in-wrong-st